# Can a macro be used when a user clicks the Insertpicture button in a picture placeholder in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have developed a server-based image library for a client that is accessed from a Tender Word template.

They have now asked for a new PowerPoint template that can import images from this Library. I have put together macros that can import specific images, but I need the user to select the one they want each time. For example, on a team slide, where there are six placeholders, they click the button and a macro shows the image library folder, not the default folder.

I would like to get this macro to work whenever the user clicks an import button in a picture placeholder, but can find a way of doing it.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3):

How about this approach

- Prepare the PowerPoint template and add a tag to each placeholder shape
- Create a macro that traps `WindowSelectionChange` events
- When the event occurs check if the selected shape has the tag that you added before and bring up your import dialog if yes

Comment: Thanks Paul. This is certainly a possibility. I will look into this and see what I can find.

Comment: The 'Import Picture from File' button in the placeholder seems to be hard coded to My Pictures folder and I can't get it to switch path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe PPT has an `Event` that would trap this user behavior.  Looking over my Event Class module, I don't see anything that looks like an obvious solution.

One idea you might look in to is customize a `Context Menu` to include a command that will execute this macro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862(v=office.14).aspx#odc_xl_ta_CustomExcelContextMenus_AddControlsUsingRibbonX

However, MS has limited the ability to manipulate `Context Menus` in 2007+ versions of Office applications. For example, they no longer allow you to manipulate certain context menus (the one that comes to mind from my experience is the Chart Context Menu in Excel), so maybe this idea will not work, either.

Comment: Hi David. I used a custom menu in the Word solution Tender, but PowerPoint has a whole load of restrictions compared to Word. Thanks for the suggestion.